# How can I solve this error on debug console? [flutter/vscode]

Tags: flutter, gradle, build.gradle

I'm so tired of this error..
what can i do?
some odd thing is that this same code in github just work on my friend's computer
i just git cloned every code
sorry for not familiar with English

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Building with Flutter multidex support enabled.
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://downloads.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.0-all.zip
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1920)
Retrying Gradle Build: #1, wait time: 100ms
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1520)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network.
```

i tried flutter clean.. etc
i tried to create new folder and git clone one more time

Answer (score 0):

You add this line in android app gradle file

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

if this solution not work then check android studio version , gradle version, gradle-wrapper-properties version, flutter environment sdk in pubspecc.yaml compatible.

Comment: I checked it doesn't works.. and,, I checked all the version.

Comment: I have another solution .First you create new project in you studio and move current project libs folder in  your new project which you have create and also add dependencies which you use in pubspace.yaml.                                                                   Update all letest version in project & android studio version.

Comment: I've already did it last

Comment: Now you have to follow one by one step like add one by one add dependency run project and check which dependency create problem and add build gradle compatible version. after that successful you can add all libs folder files .